# How to remove whitespaces inside an XML tag, closing tag and spaces between tags

Tags: php, regex, xml

I'm having difficulty in removing whitespaces between XML opening and closing tags and well as between tags. As you can see from the XML code provided that there is whitespace inside the < priip> tag and several others while the closing tag for  also has whitespace < /properties>

I have tried several modifications of preg_replace(), trim () but can't seem to get this working appropriately. I understand that usually, one should reject invalid XML rather than try to fix it but I have to fix this.

**XML**

```
< priip> 
< data> 
< product> 
< priipCloudProductTemplate>otc</priipCloudProductTemplate> 
< priipCloudProductType>fxSwap</priipCloudProductType> 
< productIdentifier>RBI_fxSwap_EURUSD_long_1Y2D_EUR</productIdentifier> < /product> 
< document> 
< type>final</type> 
< /document> 
< properties> 
< includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>true</includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert> 
< /properties> 
< tradeDate>2018-01-18</tradeDate> 
< effectiveDate>2018-01-20</effectiveDate> 
< fxSwap> 
<holder>client</holder> 
 <currencyPair>EURUSD</currencyPair> 
 <notionalAmount>1000000</notionalAmount> 
 <notionalAmountCurrency>EUR</notionalAmountCurrency> 
 <terminationDate>2019-01-20</terminationDate> 
 <forwardRate> 
 <value>1.25620</value> 
 </forwardRate> .......
```

I expect the output to be without unnecessary whitespaces

**Output XML**

```
<priip> 
<data> 
<product> 
<priipCloudProductTemplate>otc</priipCloudProductTemplate> 
<priipCloudProductType>fxSwap</priipCloudProductType> 
<productIdentifier>RBI_fxSwap_EURUSD_long_1Y2D_EUR</productIdentifier></product> 
<document> 
<type>final</type> 
</document> 
<properties> <includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>true</includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert> 
</properties> 
<tradeDate>2018-01-18</tradeDate> 
<effectiveDate>2018-01-20</effectiveDate> 
<fxSwap> 
<holder>client</holder> 
<currencyPair>EURUSD</currencyPair> 
<notionalAmount>1000000</notionalAmount> 
<notionalAmountCurrency>EUR</notionalAmountCurrency> 
<terminationDate>2019-01-20</terminationDate> 
<forwardRate> 
<value>1.25620</value> 
</forwardRate> ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
$xml = '< priip>
< data>
< product>
< priipCloudProductTemplate>otc</priipCloudProductTemplate>
< priipCloudProductType>fxSwap</priipCloudProductType>
< productIdentifier>RBI_fxSwap_EURUSD_long_1Y2D_EUR</productIdentifier> < /product>
< document>
< type>final</type>
< /document>
< properties>
< includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>true</includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>
< /properties>
< tradeDate>2018-01-18</tradeDate>
< effectiveDate>2018-01-20</effectiveDate>
< fxSwap>
<holder>client</holder>
 <currencyPair>EURUSD</currencyPair>
 <notionalAmount>1000000</notionalAmount>
 <notionalAmountCurrency>EUR</notionalAmountCurrency>
 <terminationDate>2019-01-20</terminationDate>
 <forwardRate>
 <value>1.25620</value>
 </forwardRate>';

echo preg_replace('/(<)\s(\/?(?:[A-Z][A-Z\d]*)\b[^>]*>)/i', '$1$2', $xml);

/*
 * Will produce...

<priip>
<data>
<product>
<priipCloudProductTemplate>otc</priipCloudProductTemplate>
<priipCloudProductType>fxSwap</priipCloudProductType>
<productIdentifier>RBI_fxSwap_EURUSD_long_1Y2D_EUR</productIdentifier> </product>
<document>
<type>final</type>
</document>
<properties>
<includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>true</includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>
</properties>
<tradeDate>2018-01-18</tradeDate>
<effectiveDate>2018-01-20</effectiveDate>
<fxSwap>
<holder>client</holder>
 <currencyPair>EURUSD</currencyPair>
 <notionalAmount>1000000</notionalAmount>
 <notionalAmountCurrency>EUR</notionalAmountCurrency>
 <terminationDate>2019-01-20</terminationDate>
 <forwardRate>
 <value>1.25620</value>
 </forwardRate>
*/
```

Will work even whit tags who cotains attributes like `< tag arg="val">`, and the other solution will not, unfortunately i can't comment his answer bacause of my low reputation...

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped and worked as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think its can help you.

```php
<?php

    $xml = <<<XML

    < priip> 
    < data> 
    < product> 
    < priipCloudProductTemplate>otc</priipCloudProductTemplate> 
    < priipCloudProductType>fxSwap</priipCloudProductType> 
    < productIdentifier>RBI_fxSwap_EURUSD_long_1Y2D_EUR</productIdentifier> < /product> 
    < document> 
    < type>final</type> 
    < /document> 
    < properties> 
    < includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>true</includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert> 
    < /properties> 
    < tradeDate>2018-01-18</tradeDate> 
    < effectiveDate>2018-01-20</effectiveDate> 
    < fxSwap> 
    <holder>client</holder> 
     <currencyPair>EURUSD</currencyPair> 
     <notionalAmount>1000000</notionalAmount> 
     <notionalAmountCurrency>EUR</notionalAmountCurrency> 
     <terminationDate>2019-01-20</terminationDate> 
     <forwardRate> 
     <value>1.25620</value> 
     </forwardRate> .......


    XML;

    $x = preg_replace('/(<)(\s+)\/?(\w+\>)/m', "$1$3", $xml);

    echo $x;


    ?>
```

Return XML

```
<priip> 
<data> 
<product> 
<priipCloudProductTemplate>otc</priipCloudProductTemplate> 
<priipCloudProductType>fxSwap</priipCloudProductType> 
<productIdentifier>RBI_fxSwap_EURUSD_long_1Y2D_EUR</productIdentifier> <product> 
<document> 
<type>final</type> 
<document> 
<properties> 
<includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert>true</includeEarlyRedemptionInExtraordinaryEventsAlert> 
<properties> 
<tradeDate>2018-01-18</tradeDate> 
<effectiveDate>2018-01-20</effectiveDate> 
<fxSwap> 
<holder>client</holder> 
 <currencyPair>EURUSD</currencyPair> 
 <notionalAmount>1000000</notionalAmount> 
 <notionalAmountCurrency>EUR</notionalAmountCurrency> 
 <terminationDate>2019-01-20</terminationDate> 
 <forwardRate> 
 <value>1.25620</value> 
 </forwardRate> .......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple php `str_replace()` with an array mapping to remove the `>space` with `>` and `<space` with `<`

```
$expected_xml = str_replace(['< ','> '],['<','>'],$xml);
echo $expected_xml;
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Jq5Mi

Comment: This will replace all spaces - they may be in content!

Comment: so values will be damaged also.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes got it now. thnx :)

Comment: Please have a look on my edit and demo now, hope it'll not replace whitespace inside the content